# Python string formatting q

Tags: python

I am learning to write python and I am writing some scripts according to what a book says. The code is as follows

```
cars = 100 
space_in_a_car = 4 
drivers = 30
passengers = 90
cars_not_driven = cars - drivers 
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / cars_driven 

print "There are % cars available." % cars
print "There are only % drivers available." % drivers
print "There will be % empty cars today." % cars_not_driven
print "We can transport % people today" % carpool_capacity         <--Line 24
print "We have % to carpool today." % passengers
print "We need to put about % in each car." % average_passengers_per_car
```

It says that on line 24, which is the line that says that we can transport % people today, has an error. The Terminal says that there is an unsupported format character "p", but I cannot seem to find the problem. All of the lines follow the exact same format so when I look over the code I cannot see the problem. I need to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

The print statements you included are not valid. Using string formatting with the % sign requires that you provide a format character after the percent. [This page](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php) explains it pretty well.

This is one way to do it:

```
cars = 100 
space_in_a_car = 4 
drivers = 30
passengers = 90
cars_not_driven = cars - drivers 
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / cars_driven 

print "There are %d cars available." % cars
print "There are only %d drivers available." % drivers
print "There will be %d empty cars today." % cars_not_driven
print "We can transport %d people today" % carpool_capacity
print "We have %d to carpool today." % passengers
print "We need to put about %d in each car." % average_passengers_per_car
```

So, either you copied from the book incorrectly, or the book is wrong, or the book provided the above code as an exercise for you to modify it so that it will run properly. That said, this way of doing string formatting in python is very old -- there are more modern ways of achieving this nowadays that you can read about in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for your version of python.

Comment: OK thank you. I think that the problem was that I didn't understand that I needed a format character after the % sign.